# IE9 is duplicating master page content

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

Create a brand new asp.net webforms project.
Add a master page and a webforms page that uses that master page.

**master page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="AspWeird.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="main_content_container">
            <div id="main_content_row">
                <div id="main_content_column">
                  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>

                <div id="side_content_column">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**webforms page**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AspWeird.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<h2>Hello World</h2>

<div>
    <form></form>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Now view the page in IE9 and open the F12 Developer tools

If you look you will see that part of the master page looks like it is in the DOM twice...**examining the network capture the server looks to be returning the correct HTML.**
Do not have any problems with firefox or chrome.

[screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1994980/IE9_duplicate_content.PNG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1994980/IE9_duplicate_content.PNG)

This only happens with the

```
<div><form></form></div>
```

block in there. If you remove it everything is normal.

[Whole project zipped up](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1994980/AspWeird.zip)

Comment: I don't know if this is related to the problem at all, but I don't think you're supposed to have a nested form tag.

Comment: I have the same issue only occurring in IE9 in an asp.net project. So weird. I'm trying to play around with z-index when I noticed it was duplicating my tool tip markup.

Answer (score 3):

In general, ASP.NET works based on a single form tag. That you see the symptoms you do and not an outright error is really the only surprising part. Thus, you should not try to nest form tags. From the lowest master to the outer most derived page should only have a single form tag.

---

**Update**

This definitely looks like a bug in IE9. If you use Fiddler to view the actual markup being sent across the wire, the code is not duplicated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple `<form>`s in MVC, although they shouldn't be nested.

Comment: Yes captain obvious I know to not nest form tags. Since everything in webforms is nested inside a form it can't be helped (without a lot of work) in the particular case where i noticed this behavior. My reason for posting this is because IE is doing something really strange and I want to find out why.

Comment: @chrisortman - Your OP states that this is happening in IE9. Does that imply that this behavior does not happen in other browsers such as FF or Chrome?

Comment: @chrisortman: You shouldn't insult the people trying to help you (i.e. "captain obvious") -- Apparently, IE9 handles nested forms in this odd way, since they aren't part of a valid HTML layout. The weird part is that another browser does handle it, not that IE9 doesn't.

Comment: @JohnFischer you're right, sorry, that wasn't very nice of me.

Comment: I would say it is 'weird' of IE9. Cloning part of the page tree in order to display a nested form is going to look right 0% of the time. At least FF and chrome just treat it as another element and do their best.

Comment: @John Fisher,@chrisortman - I wonder if this is simply a bug in IE9's developer tools. What does Fiddler say is actually being sent across the wire?

Comment: Looks fine over the wire which is how I knew the problem wasn't webforms and its insistence on a single form tag. I don't think the bug is in the dev tools though, I first noticed the issue because I had a page that looked fine in every browser but IE9, in IE9 it had this huge blank gap. I whittled the cause down to the nested <form> tag

Comment: @chrisortman - The page renders fine on IE9 on my machine. It might be a bug in IE9 in general.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think you see any visual evidence in my example because there isn't anything else in the form.

Comment: @chrisortman - Although, an interesting question is "What should it do given that the markup is invalid?" TBH, I'm not sure. Switch to quirks mode maybe?

Comment: It should **not** generate its own markup. To make the behavior even more evident adding a 'test' class on one of the divs <div id="main_content_container" class="test"> and then checking with jquery $('.test').length shows 2 ... i would say this behavior could break a lot of sites

Comment: @chrisortman - That you are trying to view invalid markup *should* break a site with respect to how it is viewed. My hope is that it would break as hard as possible so that I know to fix it. Better yet would be for VS to catch it and give me an error. That the form of breaking is magically adding markup isn't ideal but as long as the look breaks horribly enough to fix it, it is what it is.

Comment: @chris you're asking to have a form rendered inside another form. However the requirements (that is the HTML spec) strictly says this will never happen! So IE renders both form tags but not nested and it renders the inner html of both. The markup you see in dev tools is still invalid but at least IE tries to correct your error. If IE should render your nested forms what should be the result of clicking a submit in the inner form? Plating only the inner form, posting the outer form incl. Fields from the inner or two posts? Either way it would be weird

Comment: @Thomas.  Thanks for posting this!  Your "nested tags are wrong" answer revealed to me the source of a different, but related problem I'd been trying to fix for HOURS and pulling my hair out over.  Thank you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Nested form tags makes for invalid HTML and the rendering you see in IE9 is very likely a result of that. The DOM you see in developer tools is what is rendered not what is received as a HTTP response